# perl convert EPOCH time with DateTime module

Tags: perl

I have an epoch time and want to convert it to somthing like Jul 10 14:11:23 ,

Currently I use the following :

```
my ($sec,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon,$year,$wday,$yday,$isdst) = localtime(time);
    my @months = ("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec");
    my $date = sprintf("%3s %2d %02d:%02d:%02d", $months[$mon], $mday, $hour, $min, $sec);
```

I wonder if its possible to convert epoch time to somthing like "Jul 10 14:11:23" with DateTime module if yes could someone provide an example

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [`strftime`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime#strftime-Patterns) function of [`DateTime`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use DateTime;

my $dt = DateTime->from_epoch( epoch => time );

print $dt->strftime("%b %d %H:%M:%S");
```

Outputs:

```
Jul 07 20:39:11
```

Answer (score 3):

For this one task, you could use POSIX, core perl for a long time.

```
use POSIX 'strftime';

print strftime "%b %d %H:%M:%S", localtime;
```

Comment: If you've got a lot of dates to convert, this should also run faster than DateTime.